# issues with how to hide/unhide content when a link is click using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a code below. when the page is loaded, it will show form data, when i click on comment link, it will hide the form content. when I click the comment link again it will show the hidden content.

Now what I want is to hide the form content on Page Load. it will show/hide the content only when the comment link is click. please how do I achieve that

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on("click",".addComment",function(){

        var element = $(this);
        var id = element.attr("id");

        $('#commentBox'+id).slideToggle(200);
        $('#comment'+id).focus();
        $('#comment'+id).val('');
        $('#comment'+id).attr("placeholder", "Write a Comment..");


    });

});


</script>
</head>
<body>

<li id="post<?php $pid ='2';  $countcom='0'; echo $pid;?>">
<a class="addComment" id="<?php echo $pid?>">Comment</a>
<div id="loadcomment<?php echo $pid;?>">
</div>
<div id="commentBox<?php echo $pid?>" class="combox" <?php if($countcom>0){?> style="display:block;" <?php }?>>
<form action="" method="post" name="<?php echo $pid?>">
<textarea name="comment" class="comment" type="text" id="comment<?php echo $pid?>" style="float:left;" placeholder="Write a Comment..">
</textarea>
<input name="comBtn" class="comBtn" id="<?php echo $pid?>" type="submit" value="Comment me" />
</form>
</div>
</li>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="commentBox<?php echo $pid?>" class="combox" <?php if($countcom>0){?> style="display:block;" <?php } else {
    echo 'style="display:none;';}?>>
```

Comment: I think it looks better if you use echo instead of closing PHP tag.

Comment: But why are you using this variable countcom anyways?

This will work just as fine

`<div id="commentBox<?php echo $pid?>" class="combox" style="display: none">` It is set to 0 and you are checking if it is bigger than 0.

Comment: **@Isuru Kottachchi**, read the comments above and the second thing is what if he actually uses the variable **$countcom**

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

I am not quite understanding which node you would like hidden...but you can just set the CSS styling of the element that you want to be hidden on Document Ready to `display: none`!

Take a look at **[my CodePen](https://codepen.io/tcraw/pen/oparGw)** to see how this CSS setting can be utilized with JQuery `toggle()` or `show()` methods.

## Explanation

In JQuery, `.toggle()`, `.hide()`, and `.show()` methods essentially just flip the CSS styling property `display` of the target element between `display: none` and `display: inline`.

## References

**1. Go to the Source!**

[The documentation on the JQuery webpage](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) for *.hide()* breaks this down pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like the problem is misunderstood, and in few words, a DIV needs to be hidden at the point of page load. To do this, the easiest way would be to mark the div hidden by default. How?

```
<div id="commentBox<?php echo $pid?>" class="combox" hidden>
```

That's all you got to do and your exiting code will work with the toggle.

Comment: @Mehdi Idrizi - your solution seems more of a workaround than a solution. OP simply needs a div to be hidden during loading and that is as easy as setting the div to hidden at load. Why use a magical variable to achieve this?

Comment: @Mehdi Idrizi - my whole point is about using the variable $countcom. If this variable is solely being used for the purpose of controlling the visibility of the div, it is completely contradicting the requirement of having it hidden on load because the value MUST be 0. Therefore you wouldn't need to use this variable at all. But if this variable is being used for something else, then it would contradict with the button toggle behavior where both the variable and button trying to control display behavior. I am certain that is not what is intended to be....